# Prove that all integers of the form $p^k$ appear in a sequence $a_n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $v_p(x)$ be the exponent of prime $p$ when the natural number $x$ is prime factorized.

> If $a_1=1$, $a_{n+1}=a_n+1+v_p(a_n)$, prove that that all integers of the form $p^k$ appear in the sequence $a_n$ ($k\geq0 $ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$).

My teacher gave me a hint to use the inequality $p^j\geq j+1$ ($j\geq0 $ and $j\in\mathbb{Z}$)
but I couldn't find a way to solve it. Please teach me how to solve it!

Comment: What is $v_p(a_1)$?

Comment: If x does not have p as a prime factor, $v_p(x)=0$.

Comment: So $v_p(a_1)=0$

Comment: Oh okay. I got it now.

Comment: Oh and also $n=1,2,3,4...$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that for some $k$, $p^k$ is not an element of the sequence. The sequence is clearly increasing. Suppose $a_n$ is the highest member of the sequence such that $a_n <p^k$. Then $a_n < p^k < a_{n+1}$. Say, we write, $a_n = p^k-s$ ($s>0$)and $a_{n+1} =p^k+r$ ($r>0$). By the definition,
$$ a_{n+1}= p^k-s + 1 +v_p(a_n).$$
It is thus clear that $v_p(a_n) = s+r-1$ as $a_{n+1} = p^k+r$. By definition of $v_p(a_n)$, this implies, $p^{s+r-1}$ divides $a_n$. This in turn implies, $p^{r+s-1}$ divides $s$ (Why?). Clearly, $r+s-1 \geq s$ and your professor has rightly said to use $p^s \geq s+1 >s$. How can then $p^{r+s-1}$ which is greater than or equal to $p^s$ divide $s$?

Comment: This in turn implies, $p^{r+s-1}$ divides $s$
Could you tell me why?

Comment: If $p^{r+s-1}$ divides $p^k-s$, then $r+s-1$ must be strictly less than $k$. If not, then $p^{r+s-1}$ would be greater than $p^k-s$. Thus, if $r+s-1<k$, then $p^{r+s-1}$ divides $p^k$. Hence $p^{r+s-1}$ divides $p^k-(p^k-s) = s.$